# Django POST method giving 500 internal server error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I am currently working on a Django project. When I am sending a GET request using CURL it is working fine, but in case of POST request it is giving me 500 internal error. I think it has something to do with csrf token and I have no idea what to do with it or how csrf will solve my error.

I have also set DEBUG = False and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] in settings.py, but then also I am getting the same error:

## Server Error (500)

Here is some piece of my code:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'project.views',
    url(r'^users/$', 'userList', name='userList'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', 'userDetail', name='userDetail'),
)
```

This is a function from views,py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])

def userList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = users.objects.all()
        serializer = UsersSerializer(user, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UsersSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
            serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is the command I am using in the terminal:

curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/ -d '{"username":"root", "email":"abc@gmail.com"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"

Django version number : 1.9

In POSTMAN I am getting the error as:

{
  "username": [
    "This field is required."
  ],
  "email": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}

Comment: Do you have access to the server's logs? What does the traceback say?

Comment: If you set DEBUG to True, you will see the full error. What does it say?

Comment: When I used POSTMAN it gave me an error:
{
  "detail": "Unsupported media type \"text/plain;charset=UTF-8\" in request."
}

Comment: Can you add the definition of your UsersSerializer class?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be [`data=request.data`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/)(lower case `data`)?

Comment: In a Django view function, post data is typically in `request.POST`.

Comment: Nope it's not working.

I have tried both data=request.data and request.post, but both seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually shoudn't the data be assigned to post like this?

```
serializer = UsersSerializer(data=request.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending data with header `Content-Type: application/json`, the request data is available in `request.body`:

```py
serializer = UsersSerializer(data=request.body)
```

In this case, `request.body` is a bytestring. In the case that your `UsersSerializer` class needs a different data type,

For string, you need to call `decode` method on the bytestring,

```py
serializer = UsersSerializer(data=request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

For dictionary, you would need to parse the json string,

```py
import json

# your userList function

serializer = UsersSerializer(data=json.loads(request.body))
```

Note that if you need to parse the json body, you may want to use a try-catch block in case the user sends a json-non-serializable string or does not include a body in the request.